# r marginal effects plot for multiple objects

Tags: r, marginal-effects

My question is how to plot marginal effects or adjusted predictions using `ggeffects()` or `ggemmeans()` when I run my model on multiple subsets of data using `dlply` which creates summary estimates as multiple objects

**First**, I start with a toy dataset.

```
   library(lme4)
   data(Soybean)
   library(plyr)
   library(nlme)
   library(ggplot2)
   library(ggeffects)

head(Soybean)

       Plot   Variety Year Time weight  
1988.1 1988F1       F 1988   14  0.106 
1988.2 1988F1       F 1988   21  0.261 
1988.3 1988F1       F 1988   28  0.666  
1988.4 1988F1       F 1988   35  2.110  
1988.5 1988F1       F 1988   42  3.560  
1988.6 1988F1       F 1988   49  6.230
```

**Second**, I fit model with Variety as random intercept on **each subset of dataset by Year**.

```
table(Soybean$Year)

1988 1989 1990 
 156  128  128 
 
table(Soybean$Variety)

  F   P 
204 208 

# Fit LME model for each subset(Soybean)
MxM1 <- dlply(Soybean,
                    "Year",
                    function(x)
                      lme(fixed = weight ~ Time,
                          random = ~ 1 |Variety ,
                           data=x, na.action=na.exclude))
```

These are the coefficients of Random intercept (Variety) from the model.

2 varieties, 3 years , 6 different intercepts,

```
  ldply(MxM1, coef)
  Year (Intercept)  Time
1 1988       -8.65 0.349
2 1988       -7.73 0.349
3 1989       -6.71 0.242
4 1989       -4.04 0.242
5 1990       -7.28 0.309
6 1990       -6.63 0.309
```

How do I plot the marginal effects or adjusted predictions using `ggeffects` or `ggemeans` for `lme` estimates from multiple datasets ?

Expecting a marginal effects or conditional effects plot like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?  Here's an example with the `Chile` data from `carData`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(dplyr)
library(ggeffects)
data("Chile", package="carData")
Chile$votey = ifelse(Chile$vote == "Y", 1, 0)
```

Run the models as you suggest using `dlply()`.

```r
mods <- plyr::dlply(Chile, "sex", function(x)glmer(votey ~ age + education + income + (1|region), 
                                           data=x,
                                           family=binomial))
```

Use `map()` from `purrr` to generate predictions using `ggpredict()` and then turn the results into raw data frames. (you could just as easily use `lapply()`.) Then, you bind the predictions together into a single data frame.

```r
preds <- purrr::map(mods, function(x)ggpredict(x, c("age[all]", "region"), type="re")  %>% as.data.frame())
preds <- bind_rows(preds, .id="sex")
```

Then, make the plot:

```r
ggplot(preds, aes(x=x, y=predicted, ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high, color=group, fill=group)) + 
  #geom_ribbon(col="transparent", alpha=.2) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(sex ~ .)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Dave I am getting a warning , `Warning message Could not recover model data from environment. Please make sure your data is available in your workspace` when i run the line `preds <- purrr::map(mods,.......`

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai I'm using R 4.2.2 with ggeffects v 1.1.5 and I don't get that error.  Could you post a big enough snippet of your data that we can run your model and hopefully reproduce the problem?